# Improve code to save and populate asp.net checkboxlist values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have inherited an application that has code to save and populate values in a asp.net checkboxlist control.  The existing code is very lengthy and does not appear to be efficient to me.  I plan on rewriting this application and have complete control over the database design.  Can someone offer any advice on how I can improve and shorten the code below.

All of the checkboxlist items are stored in a sql table as bit fields.  Each row of checkboxlist values are assigned to a userid.  Once again, my goal is to find a more efficient way to save and populate selected checkboxlist items with less code. thanks.

```
Database Design
UserID  AA  BC  AC
1       1    1  0 
2       0    1  1
3       1    1  0 
4       1    1  1

'Code to populate selected checkboxlist items

Dim CodeData as datarow
CodeData = CodeDataTable.Rows(0)
For Each li As ListItem In Me.cblCodes.Items
                    If li.Text = "AA" Then
                       If Not CodeData.IsOneNull Then
                           If CodeData.One = True Then
                               li.Selected = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                  If li.Text = "BC" Then
                    If Not CodeData.IsTwoNull Then
                        If CodeData.Two = True Then
                            li.Selected = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
         If li.Text = "AC" Then
                    If Not CodeData.IsTwoNull Then
                        If CodeData.Two = True Then
                            li.Selected = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If  
            ......

Next

'Code to save checkboxlist values
 Dim AA As Boolean = False
 Dim BC As Boolean = False
 Dim AC As Boolean = False
 Dim AD As Boolean = False


 AA = Me.cblCodes.Items.FindByText("AA").Selected()
 BC = Me.cblCodes.Items.FindByText("BC").Selected
 AC = Me.cblCodes.Items.FindByText("AC").Selected
 AD = Me.cblCodes.Items.FindByText("AD").Selected

 CodeTableAdapter.UpdateCodes(UserID,AA,BC,AC,AD.......)
```

The table adapter calls the stored procedure which sets the sql bit fields to the appropriate boolean values.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your code / question... can you elaborate more??? Or, maybe someone else does...

Comment: Code review questions are off-topic on StackOverflow. Check out [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a better to way save checkboxlist values to the database as bit values with less code.